# Using Perl how can I clean up left over directories with no files?

Tags: linux, perl, file, directory

There is a specific directory which is used as a temp/scratch directory by some program.
E.g. `/a/b/c/work`
Under work multiple hierarchical directories may exist e.g.

```
/a/b/c/work/  
            \d1/   
               \d1.1  
             \d2
                \d2.2
```

What I want is to clean up this work directory as there are left over files that take space.
Essentially I need to delete all subdirectories under work that the leaf directory is empty.
So if d1.1 is empty but d2.2 has files then delete everything under d1 (including d1) but not d2.
What is the cleanest/standard way to do this in perl?
I thought to use a solution with backticks e.g. rm -rf etc but I thought there could be some better way than coding sequences of ls folowed by rm

**Note:** Just to be clear. I want a solution in Perl as this is not a one time thing and I dont want to do this manually each time

Answer (score 4):

If you use `find` command this way you can achieve it.

```
find /path/to/dir -empty -type d -delete
```

Where,

`-empty`   Only find empty files and make sure it is a regular file or a directory.

`-type d`  Only match directories.

`-delete`  Delete files.

Always put `-delete` option at the end of find command as find command line is evaluated as an expression, so putting `-delete` first will make find try to delete everything below the starting points you specified.

To automate this in shell script follow below code:

```
path=`pwd`

find $path -empty -type d -delete
```

or you can give certain input as arguments of shell script like `myShell.sh /path/to/mydir` in that case the following code will be do the work,

```
$path=$1

find $path -empty -type d -delete
```

As for if you really want to go for perl you can find your answer as follows

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Util;

my $path = '...';

my $fu         = File::Util->new();
my @all_dirs   = $fu->list_dir($path, '--recurse', '--dirs-only');
my @empty_dirs = grep { not $fu->list_dir($_) } @all_dirs;
```

also a short method

```
perl -MFile::Find -e"finddepth(sub{rmdir},'.')"
```

which is explained very good [here](http://duramecho.com/ComputerPrograms/DeleteEmptyDirectories/).

Comment: 1) Will this delete all empty parent directories? 2) How do I do this in perl? Just use backticks?

Comment: You have to set the directory path of which you want to delete the empty directories and @Jim I hope you have asked as per Linux shell requirement.

Comment: I need to do this automatically and not "monitor" this directory and issue this command manually as this is not a one time thing. I am sorry if my OP was not clear

Comment: You still can use a shell script to determine the current directory using `pwd` and use the variable to `find` command as target. I'm editing as per new updated OP.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `determine the current directory using pwd`. I know the directory. It is 1 specific under which the subdirectories that end up in empty leaf hierarchies must be deleted

Comment: I did not understand your perl example. This finddepth will delete all directories in the path but it does not check if they are empty

Comment: Why don't you check the shell script rather perl cause they too are portable and flexible to use.

Comment: Well because I don't really know much about shell scripting and I would like a perl script to run it as a job daily